# When to write prefix re- or ré-

Tags: verbes, orthographe, néologismes, préfixes

I am having a following issue: There are a lot of verbs with prefix re- or ré- but I mix them a lot. E.g.

relayer regorger réparer répandre reprendre reparaître

Are there any rules for writing this prefix? Why are some written with re- and some with ré-?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the prefix is used to express something is repeated, it is always *re* like:

- prendre -> reprendre
- paraître -> reparaître

except if the verb starts with a vowel in which case it is either *ré*:

- agir -> réagir
- essayer -> réessayer
- élire -> réélire
- inventer -> réinventer

or *r* with elision:

- emballer -> remballer
- ouvrir -> rouvrir
- emporter -> remporter
- échapper -> réchapper
- épandre -> répandre

There is no rule to know if the elision is to be made or not. In particular a very common mistake is to use *réouvrir* instead of *rouvrir* due to the proximity of *réouverture*.

Otherwise, when the verb happen to start with *re* for other reasons, both forms can be found, depending on the verb root/etymology.

- recroqueviller
- recruter
- refuser
- regretter
- relater
- relativiser
- relaxer
- remorquer
- régner
- réguler
- répéter
- répondre
- révéler

The verb *réparer* is kind of an exception as etymologically, it cames from the Latin *re-parare*.

Other exceptions found in [espacefrancais.com/laccentuation-de-la-voyelle-e](http://www.espacefrancais.com/laccentuation-de-la-voyelle-e/) are:

- concilier -> réconcilier
- chauffer -> réchauffer

Comment: Thank you very much. If you could post a link to the external site where I can read more about this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Useful info about writing e/é/è: http://www.espacefrancais.com/laccentuation-de-la-voyelle-e/